# Troubleshooting SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am seeing a weird issue while executing an SQL stored procedure. Below is the format of the stored proc:

```
CREATE PROC abc
(
  @status int=0 output
)
AS
BEGIN TRY

--Does some transactions 

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
SET @status=-1
END CATCH

return @status
```

I understand I should have added/logged more details like Error Number, Error Message etc in my catch block but I didnt realize such an issue would occur. Currently, the stored procedure in production sometimes returns a -1 status. The strange part is all the transactions in the try block have been successfully committed. I dont understand then why is the procedure getting into the catch block. I tried to manually execute the procedure with same data  it completes successfully and returns status=0. I added extra logging in test environment and tested more than 300 times, but was not able to reproduce the issue. In production I am not allowed to make any changes. Hence, I asked our DBA's to enable trace logging, but that didnt help us much in getting any exception details.

I would really appreciate if there is any way I can troubleshoot this issue. Also are there any options for the DBA's to monitor this procedure and capture the exception

Comment: Maybe the procedure is called with `@status` set to `-1` originally. You should be initializing `@status` to `0` inside the procedure, not relying on default value of the parameter.

Comment: Look at the SQL Server Profile trace to identify how the procedure is called, then you can easily rerun and check its execution plan etc.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov My bad, in BEGIN Try block status is set to 0. I didnt mention it at the above snippet

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen, From the trace I got the procedure structure of how it is called and I manually ran it the same way and it executed with status 0

Comment: @marak, I don't know how to figure out what is going on without changing the procedure and adding more logging to it.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Yes, I agree. I gave up for now and I am planning to deploy a new version of the procedure in the next drop.